# IOS: delete a file in a directory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app I download a pdf file with an ASiHttpRequest and I have these instructions:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [currentDownload setDownloadDestinationPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"]];
```

it work fine at first time, and I can open this file.pdf, but when I download a second time this pdf, it seems that it not replace the file but do a merge.

before I do this, but it doesn't work where is the problem, or what's the best way to delete this file.pdf from its path?

```
    - (void) removeFile{
  NSString *extension = @"pdf";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPDF = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPDF error:NULL];
    NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
    NSString *filename;
    while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

        if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {

            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectoryPDF stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

now I use this method

```
- (void) removeFile{


    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingString:@"/file.pdf"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"Documents directory before: %@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error]);


        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"file exist and I delete it");

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];

            NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
        }

    NSLog(@"Documents directory after: %@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error]);


}
```

this method recognize that in directory there is "file.pdf" in NSLog

```
NSLog(@"Documents directory before: %@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error]);
```

but it crash after

```
"NSLog(@"file exist and I delete it");"
```

and I have only a "lldb" in consolle.

Comment: maybe the problem reside in that ``ASIHttpRequest`` is detecting that the file exist and is assuming that you are resuming the download, try setting ``allowResumeForFileDownloads`` to ``NO``

Comment: mmmm no it don't work...

Comment: ok, another option could be a cache problem, you can check the value of the property ``didUseCachedResponse`` to check if the response was obtained from the cache or not, and playing with ``cachePolicy`` and ``cacheStoragePolicy`` you can enable/disable the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you don't remove the file before downloading a new one and ASIHttpRequest sees that there's already a file with the same name and appends data to it instead of replacing the file. I'm not sure about the PDF format, but that shouldn't normally result in a merged **readable** file. In any case, first you need to use the error mechanism that the filemanager class offers you. Is bad to pass NULL. Very bad. So, create a NSError object and pass it to the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` and `removeItemAtPath` methods, then check the error, be sure the operations are done successfully. After that, you may want to check the extension upper case as well, as Unix based systems are case sensitive (although the simulator is not, the device is) and a `example.PDF` file will not get deleted based on your code.

Comment: yes it's the exact problem that I have...I try error but there aren't error...so I try with an upper case extension of file...

Comment: I have an error with "contentsOfDirectoryAtPath"  and it is the error log: error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0xbc40500 {NSUnderlyingError=0xbc40e70 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/345B9530-74FF-49DE-AF39-418D03C9A149/Documents/file.pdf, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder

Comment: `documentsDirectoryPDF` should not be `/var/mobile/Applications/345B9530-74FF-49DE-AF39-418D03C9A149/Documen‌​ts/file.pdf` can you print it's value to be sure?

Answer (score 3):

I use this method to delete pdf files from a local cache, with a few modifications you can adapt it to your necessities

```
- (void)removePDFFiles
{
    NSFileManager *fileMngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *cacheFiles = [fileMngr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self cacheDirectory]
                                                    error:nil];
    for (NSString *filename in cacheFiles) {
        if ([[[filename pathExtension] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
            [fileMngr removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self cacheDirectory], filename] error:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
-(BOOL) removePDF
{
    BOOL removeStatus = NO;

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* fileName = @"file.pdf"; //your file here..

    NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir, fileName];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == YES)
    {
       removeStatus = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath]; 
    }
    return removeStatus;
}
```

Comment: @blackguardian: did you fix the issue? What was the reason for the issue?